# How make a row with different columns in html

Tags: html, html-table, cell

My question is that how  can I make a row with different columns quantity ?
For example I want to have 2 columns in last row in this picture (the portion of each cell must be 50%).
Another question that I have is that how  can I make text starts from first line in a cell (center cell , in this picture) ?

[image]

My code is :

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="green" bgcolor="yellow" height="500px">
  <caption>web design homework</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">My Website</th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#77E022" height="20px" align="left">
    <td colspan="3">
      <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none">home</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none">products</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none">contact us</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">last post</td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="50%">hello my name is mohammad ghorbani and i am studying computer enginerring in arak</td>
    <td>our friends</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>our statics</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>our social pages</td>
    <td>about us</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As this is home work and also not so difficult, you just need to put some effort into learn about tables and elements. If we do it for you, you will never learn how it works. Also people here spend time on helping you with your other question and you should at least give one credit selecting their answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two primary answer categories to your question.

First, the direct answer. Think of your page as a grid. You want enough squares on the grid to be divisible by both 3 and 2. Say, 6. Then use colspan to set each column to the number of grid columns that would be needed -- so, colspan=2 for 3 columns, and colspan=3 for 2 columns.

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=6>My Website</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=6>home, products, contact us</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 style="width:33%">last post</td>
    <td colspan=2 rowspan=2 style="width:33%">hello my name</td>
    <td colspan=2 style="width:33%">our friends</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 style="width:33%">our statics</td>
    <td colspan=2 style="width:33%">24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3 style="width:50%">our social pages</td>
    <td colspan=3 style="width:50%">about us</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The other answer category is that you should avoid using tables for your layout structure. There's a LOT of Google results for this one, and it's very opinion based, so I'll just say that generally tables should be used for data, css for layouts, and using tables for layouts may be quicker but it's less flexible.

Comment: thank you man , do you have any suggestion about my second question>

Comment: Ahh, missed that one. (Should probably file a separate question for ... well, separate questions, next time. :-)) You should get comfortable with Google queries for CSS docs, it'll help you immensely. For instance, "css align top in table cell" should yield css table-styling options, at which point you'll find "vertical-align".

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working well, hope it will resolve your issue.
Add this class

```
.column{display:inline-block; width:49%;}

<table style="width:100%" border="1px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="green" bgcolor="yellow" height="500px">
<caption>web design homework</caption>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">My Website</th>
</tr>
<tr  bgcolor="#77E022"
height="20px" align="left" >
<td  colspan="3" > 
<a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none">home</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none">products</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none">contact us</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%"> last post </td>
<td valign="top" rowspan="2" width="50%"> hello my name is mohammad ghorbani and i am studying computer enginerring in arak </td>
<td> our friends </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> our statics </td>
<td> 24 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top">
<div class="column"> our social pages</div>
<div class="column"> about us </div>

</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why inline style? This is bad advice for anyone studying web design.

Comment: Just for idea, he can make class out it.

Comment: @DanWhite Inline styles load faster than style sheets because they are just one page request instead of two.

Comment: Fairly certain that placing css in the head is not an additional HTTP request. Inline styling is bad practice.

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like this was copy-pasted from OP, and adjusted specifically to address the question posed by OP. There's something to be said for surgical answers which don't also branch out into various (admittedly legit) tangential improvements.